# How to get sum of a result from Mysql in scala with play framework?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, anorm

i am working on simple scala web app and i am running a query then the play app is giving exception

**[RuntimeException: UnexpectedNullableFound(ColumnName(.SUM(score),Some(SUM(score))))]**

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: UnexpectedNullableFound(ColumnName(.SUM(score),Some(SUM(score))))]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:310) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:308) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: UnexpectedNullableFound(ColumnName(.SUM(score),Some(SUM(score))))
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at anorm.Sql$.as(Anorm.scala:535) ~[anorm_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at anorm.Sql$class.as(Anorm.scala:453) ~[anorm_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at anorm.SimpleSql.as(Anorm.scala:370) ~[anorm_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at models.Keyword$$anonfun$getBlogScore$1.apply(Keyword.scala:53) ~[na:na]
    at models.Keyword$$anonfun$getBlogScore$1.apply(Keyword.scala:52) ~[na:na]
```

**models/keyword.scala**

```
def getBlogScore(word: String, blog: String): Long={DB.withConnection{implicit c=>
 SQL("select SUM(score) from keyword where blog like {blog} and word = {word}").on('blog->blog,'word->word).as(scalar[Long].single)
}
}
```

i want to get sum of score column based on some condition.

give me some idea to solve this exception!

Comment: I think that since your query could return no values there is no guarantee you would get a Long, the possibly not there needs to be represented with an option, so you get Option[Long] instead. Cant recall how to do that right now tough, 'scalar[Long].singleOpt' maybe?

Comment: i tried `scalar[Long].singleOpt` but still getting same exception

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SQL("select SUM(score) from keyword where blog like {blog} and word = {word}").
  on('blog->blog,'word->word).
  as(scalar[Option[Long]].single).
  getOrElse(0L)
```

Comment: when i put your query then it is giving run time exception `[RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 1:class java.math.BigDecimal to Long for column ColumnName(.SUM(score),Some(SUM(score))))]`

Comment: my query that is working fine `SQL("select SUM(score) from keyword where blog like {blog} and word like {word}")
 .on('blog->blog,'word->word).as(get[Option[BigDecimal]]("SUM(score)").singleOpt.map{case Some(e)=>e}).getOrElse(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `SUM` returns `NULL` when no rows are matched.  I'm also guessing
that you probably want `0` in that case.

So you've got to deal with that situation. `Option` comes to mind. A quick look at the docs, grepping for `Option` indicates that there's a `.singleOpt`.

So you could try:

```
def getBlogScore(word: String, blog: String): Long = 
  DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("select SUM(score) from keyword where blog like {blog} and word = {word}").
      on('blog->blog,'word->word).
      as(scalar[Long].singleOpt).
      getOrElse(0L)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late but this issue is fixed in Anorm master branch: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2072